# Fault with adding numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

Good Evening from sweden!!
I need some help with my countdown code.

In the last part of the code I have added a part that will add a 0 before the last number if it is between 0 and 9 to always keep it six digits long, why isnt it working?

Hope to be hearing from you guys soon since this have to be done before the day is over

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');
@font-face {
    font-family: Khula;
    src: url('Khula-ExtraBold.ttf');
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-family: Khula;
}
#text {
    text align: center;
    font-size:9px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="date"></p>
<script>
// Countdown to
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 20, 2018 08:53:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="date"
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = days + " " + hours + " "
    + minutes;

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";

    // If the number of minutes left is between 0 and 9 add a 0 before it
    if (minutes < 10 && minutes < 0) {
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = days + " " + hours + " 0"
    + minutes;
    }
        }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `minutes < 10 && minutes < 0`? I'm guessing that is a mistake. Maybe `minutes < 10 && minutes > 0`

Comment: Also, you're missing a closing `}` for the `if (distance < 0)`

Comment: @Oram no he's not, it's just poorly indented

Comment: You're writing to the dom twice, better use a ternary operator to check if the minutes/hours/seconds is between 0-9

Comment: How do I do that? pretty new to this, Zohir?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts he put the `}` at the wrong place. Currently the `if (minutes < 10 && minutes < 0) {` runs only after the timer expired... But it doesn't run even then because of what @wowserx pointed out.

Comment: @Oram but it's not missing.

Comment: Is there a reason you are calculating seconds but not displaying them?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I concede. You're totally right. At first I didn't see it. After your comment I took a second look.

Comment: Alright but how do i add so that it also applies for hours and days??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you not familiar with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) i'ts just an if statement in one line.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 20, 2018 08:53:25").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // after the calculation we reassigning to the variables 
    // hours < 10 ? : means if hours is less than 10
    // if so assing "0" + hours to variable hours
    // : is basically the else and then we just keep as it is
    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;


    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":" +
      minutes + ":" + seconds;


    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  },
  1000);
```

```css
#date {
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: When I add that instead of the code I have now nothing at all appears on the screen for some reason?

Comment: Since it Works in snippet here, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Yup, just figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid doing multiple DOM manipulations and unneeded calculations, first check if the timer has expired. Only then, if needed construct the timer string.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 20, 2018 08:53:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  } else {
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // If the number left is between 0 and 9 add a 0 before it
    var daysStr = days < 10 ? "0" + days : days;
    var hoursStr = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    var minutesStr = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    var secondsStr = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    // Output the result in an element with id="date"
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = daysStr + " " + hoursStr + " " + minutesStr + " " + secondsStr;
  }

}, 1000);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');
@font-face {
  font-family: Khula;
  src: url('Khula-ExtraBold.ttf');
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: Khula;
}

#text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: `minutes > 0` is not needed, there's no negative values in minutes

Answer (score 0):

There's some formatting issues below your "output the result in an element comment with id date" section. The following should give you what you'd expect.

```
// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}

// If the number of days left is between 0 and 9 add a 0 before it
if (days < 10 && days >= 0) {
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "0" + days + " " + hours + " "
+ minutes;
    // If the number of hours left is between 0 and 9 add a 0 before it
    if (hours < 10 && hours >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "0" + days + " 0" + hours + " "
    + minutes;
        // If the number of minutes left is between 0 and 9 add a 0 before it
        if (minutes < 10 && minutes >= 0) {
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "0" + days + " 0" + hours + " 0"
        + minutes;
        }            
    }        
}
```